# Is this proof that a set of pairwise disjoint intervals is enumerable correct?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, real-numbers

Let $B\subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ be a set of non-degenerate pairwise disjoint intervals. I've tried to show that $B$ is enumerable in the following way: let $I\in B$, then since $I$ is non-degenerate, there is $q_I\in I\cap \mathbb{Q}$. Define $f : B\to \mathbb{Q}$ by

$$f(I)=q_I,$$

that is, for each interval, $f$ picks one arbitrary rational inside it. In that case, $f$ is injective. Of course if $f(I)=f(J)$ then $q_I=q_J$, but $I\cap J=\emptyset$, so the only way for this to be true is if $I=J$.

Now, we know $\mathbb{Q}$ to be enumerable. In that case there is an injection $\xi : \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{N}$. Setting $\varphi : B\to \mathbb{N}$ by $\varphi = \xi\circ f$ the constructed function is composition of injections, hence injection and so $B$ is enumerable.

Is this proof correct and rigorous? The only piece of it, I'm still unsure, is when defining $f$. Would some argument regarding the axiom of choice needed to make the construction of $f$ rigorous?

Answer (score 1):

The proof is fine. As defined, you seemingly appeal to the axiom of choice when you define $f$ (or rather, when you don't define $f$).

However this can be circumvented quite easily by first fixing an enumeration of $\Bbb Q$, then picking the least indexed rational within the interval (this is well-defined, because the index set is $\Bbb N$).

You can cut the middle man that lies in the last paragraph, and define the injection directly into $\Bbb N$ by returning the *index* of said rational instead.